# How do I "get the next 10 posts after post_id == x"?

Tags: plugins, php, posts, wp-query, plugin-json-api

I am building a mobile application that is pulling the json feed from a blog. I can easily query to get the latest 10 posts for example. But next, I want to be able to query the next 10. This presents me with a problem, because while pulling the first 10, another 2 posts may be added, so if I try to pull the next ten posts, I would get duplicates and get 8 unique posts instead of 10. I am trying to think of a way that I can simply get my last post id retireved, and request for the next ten posts after post id = x. I guess technically I would be getting the next 10 posts "before" that id, but I hope I explained my question.

Update:

I download recent posts

```
30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21
```

now I want to download next 10

```
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
```

Works perfect. But what happens if I want to download the next ten while x new posts were added. In this case we'll use 3 as x

Download first 10

```
30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21
```

now the next 10
Whoops. Someone added 3 new posts
still try to get next 10

```
23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14
```

Got duplicates of 23 22 21.

I want to say `get last post download aka(21) and take next ten after that`

How would I make the api in the address bar to handle this?

Comment: How the "another 2 posts may be added" works ? I mean how you are getting these 2 posts, please add your code if possible.

Comment: Let's say I do api/get_posts/?count=10. This gives me the last 10 posts. Now I would like to get 11-20. Before I get 11-20, 2 new posts are added (theoretically). Now I can't just get 11-20 I need to get 13-22

Comment: Ok, so the two post that added theoretically is on the same order as the first 10 were ? You can use `offset` on the API script which will calculate position rather using page. So query - `api/get_posts/?count=10&offset=12` would get posts

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha... While this makes a lot of sense, WP is not to good with arbitrary conditions like this and nothing like is implemented in `WP_Query` currently.

However since your issue is really chronological rather than requiring dealing with IDs, you probably can make use of [Date Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to restrict results to be older than time of oldest post you fetched instead of explicit offset by count.